# PHPQuery- Select table columns into an array

Tags: php, phpquery

I have a HTML file like with a table like this:

```
<tr valign="top" class="dselbkg" onMouseOver="this.className='selbkg'" onMouseOut="this.className='dselbkg'" > 
    <td height="20" align="center">1</td>
    <td height="20"><div align="center">16-12-2014</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">BE2105 </div></td>
    <td >PROGRAMMING IN C</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" class="dselbkg" onMouseOver="this.className='selbkg'" onMouseOut="this.className='dselbkg'" > 
    <td height="20" align="center">2</td>
    <td height="20"><div align="center">18-12-2014</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">BS1101 </div></td>
    <td >MATHEMATICS - I</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" class="dselbkg" onMouseOver="this.className='selbkg'" onMouseOut="this.className='dselbkg'" > 
    <td height="20" align="center">3</td>
    <td height="20"><div align="center">20-12-2014</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">HM3101 </div></td>
    <td >COMMUNICATIVE ENGLISH</td>
</tr>
```

I need to get each `<td>` into a separate element of an array based on the class id.

I am using PHPQuery. I tried

```
$table = $all['tr.dselbkg'];
$columns = $table['td'];
```

But what it does is puts all the columns as a single string. So `$columns[0]` prints out all the columns while `$columns[1]` is blank.

How can I take individual `<td>` as a single element in an array?

Comment: The PHPQuery library hasn't been maintained in 4 years. You might want to use more recent alternatives like DOM-Query (https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT using PHPQuery:

```
<?php

include('phpQuery.php');

$htmlString = '<tr valign="top" class="dselbkg" onMouseOver="this.className=\'selbkg\'" onMouseOut="this.className=\'dselbkg\'" > 
    <td height="20" align="center">1</td>
    <td height="20"><div align="center">16-12-2014</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">BE2105 </div></td>
    <td >PROGRAMMING IN C</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" class="dselbkg" onMouseOver="this.className=\'selbkg\'" onMouseOut="this.className=\'dselbkg\'" > 
    <td height="20" align="center">2</td>
    <td height="20"><div align="center">18-12-2014</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">BS1101 </div></td>
    <td >MATHEMATICS - I</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" class="dselbkg" onMouseOver="this.className=\'selbkg\'" onMouseOut="this.className=\'dselbkg\'" > 
    <td height="20" align="center">3</td>
    <td height="20"><div align="center">20-12-2014</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">HM3101 </div></td>
    <td >COMMUNICATIVE ENGLISH</td>
</tr> ';

$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($htmlString);

foreach (pq('tr.dselbkg') as $row){
    $columns = array();
    foreach(pq('td',$row) as $td) $columns[] = $td->nodeValue;
    $tableRows[] = $columns;
}

print_r($tableRows);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 16-12-2014
            [2] => 1ST
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)
            [3] => BE2105
            [4] => PROGRAMMING IN C
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 18-12-2014
            [2] => 1ST
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)
            [3] => BS1101
            [4] => MATHEMATICS - I
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 20-12-2014
            [2] => 1ST
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)
            [3] => HM3101
            [4] => COMMUNICATIVE ENGLISH
        )

)

*/
```

---

You can easily use [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm) to query your html.

Here's an example how to build an array from parsed `td` elements.

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$htmlString = '<tr valign="top" class="dselbkg" onMouseOver="this.className=\'selbkg\'" onMouseOut="this.className=\'dselbkg\'" > 
    <td height="20" align="center">1</td>
    <td height="20"><div align="center">16-12-2014</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">BE2105 </div></td>
    <td >PROGRAMMING IN C</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" class="dselbkg" onMouseOver="this.className=\'selbkg\'" onMouseOut="this.className=\'dselbkg\'" > 
    <td height="20" align="center">2</td>
    <td height="20"><div align="center">18-12-2014</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">BS1101 </div></td>
    <td >MATHEMATICS - I</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" class="dselbkg" onMouseOver="this.className=\'selbkg\'" onMouseOut="this.className=\'dselbkg\'" > 
    <td height="20" align="center">3</td>
    <td height="20"><div align="center">20-12-2014</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>
            (10:0 AM - 1:0 PM)</div></td>
    <td ><div align="center">HM3101 </div></td>
    <td >COMMUNICATIVE ENGLISH</td>
</tr> ';

$html = str_get_html($htmlString);

foreach($html->find('tr.dselbkg') as $tr){
    $columns = array();

    foreach($tr->find('td') as $td)
        $columns[] = $td->outertext; // outertext if you want the full td tag
        // $columns[] = $td->innertext // innertext if you just want the text inside the td tag

    $tablerows[]=$columns;
}

print_r($tablerows);

/*

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <td height="20" align="center">1</td>
            [1] => <td height="20"><div align="center">16-12-2014</div></td>
            [2] => <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>              (10:0 AM - 1:0                           PM)</div></td>
            [3] => <td ><div align="center">BE2105 </div></td>
            [4] => <td >PROGRAMMING IN C</td>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <td height="20" align="center">2</td>
            [1] => <td height="20"><div align="center">18-12-2014</div></td>
            [2] => <td ><div align="center">1ST<br>              (10:0 AM - 1:0                           PM)</div></td>
            [3] => <td ><div align="center">BS1101 </div></td>
            [4] => <td >MATHEMATICS - I</td>
        )
*/

$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

Comment: Thanks but I really need to use PHPQuery for the task!

Comment: What does `$rows = pq('ul.im-the-list > li');` do in the code?

Comment: that was a leftover that I forgot to remove, you will see that the `$rows` variable is never used, I will edit it out